# I am trying to implement an addition table for this question. However, I am not too sure how and what value to return back to the function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, append

Implement a function cal(numbers) that takes a list of n numbers and returns an n x 3 table where the first row contains the given numbers plus 1, the second row contains the given numbers plus 2, and the third row contains the given numbers plus 3.

```
def cal(numbers):
    row = 3
    for x in range(1,row+1):
        a = []
        for i in numbers :
            a.append(x+i)
        print(a)
        a = numbers
```

An example of calling cal([2,5,-3,7]) should return [[3,6,-2,8],[4,7,-1,9],[5,8,0,10]].

Comment: Instead of `print(a)` do `return a`. It is only useful to put `print(a)` when working interactively at a `>>>` prompt. In a working program the function returns the computed value to the expression that calls it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your function to just `print` the output lists and don't require those output lists, print them in the function itself.

```
def cal(numbers):
    row = 3
    for x in range(1,row+1):
        a = []
        for i in numbers :
            a.append(x+i)
        print(a)
        
cal([2,5,-3,8])
```

If you want to do some other things with the output lists, you can store them in a list inside the function and  `return` that list.

```
def cal(numbers):
    row = 3
    ans = []
    for x in range(1,row+1):
        a = []
        for i in numbers :
            a.append(x+i)
        ans.append(a)
    return ans
        
res =cal([2,5,-3,8])
print(res)
```